# Scikit Learn - Train New Model with GridSearchCV

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

If I get the optimal parameters using GridSearchCV and a pipeline, is there anyway to save the trained model, so in the future I can call the entire pipeline onto new data and generate a prediction for it? For example, I have the following pipeline followed by a gridsearchcv of the parameters:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer()),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(probability=True))),
])

parameters = {
    'vect__ngram_range': ((1, 1),(1, 2),(1,3)),  # unigrams or bigrams
    'clf__estimator__kernel': ('rbf','linear'),
    'clf__estimator__C': tuple([10**i for i in range(-10,11)]),
}

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline,parameters,n_jobs=-1,verbose=1)

print("Performing grid search...")
print("pipeline:", [name for name, _ in pipeline.steps])
print("parameters:")
pprint(parameters)
t0 = time()
#Conduct the grid search
grid_search.fit(X,y)
print("done in %0.3fs" % (time() - t0))
print()

print("Best score: %0.3f" % grid_search.best_score_)
print("Best parameters set:")
#Obtain the top performing parameters
best_parameters = grid_search.best_estimator_.get_params()
#Print the results
for param_name in sorted(parameters.keys()):
    print("\t%s: %r" % (param_name, best_parameters[param_name]))
```

Now I want to save all of these steps into a single flow so that I can apply it to a new, unseen dataset and it will use the same parameters, vectorizers and transformers to transform, implement and report back the results on it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just pickle the `GridSearchCV` object to save it and then unpickle it when you want to use it to predict new data.

```
import pickle

# Fit model and pickle fitted model
grid_search.fit(X,y)
with open('/model/path/model_pickle_file', "w") as fp:
    pickle.dump(grid_search, fp)

# Load model from file
with open('/model/path/model_pickle_file', "r") as fp:
    grid_search_load = pickle.load(fp)

# Predict new data with model loaded from disk
y_new = grid_search_load.best_estimator_.predict(X_new)
```

Comment: ... or pickle the `best_estimator_` member.